# Convert Hex to Binary and keep leading 0's Perl

Tags: perl

I have an array of hex numbers that I'd like to convert to binary numbers, the problem is, in my code it removes the leading 0's for things like 0,1,2,3. I need these leading 0's to process in a future section of my code. Is there an easy way to convert Hex to Binary and keep my leading 0's in perl?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @binary;
my @hex = ('ABCD', '0132', '2211');
foreach my $h(@hex){
my $bin = sprintf( "%b", hex($h));
push @binary, $bin;
}

foreach (@binary){
print "$_\n";
}
```

running the code gives me
`1010101111001101
100110010
10001000010001`

Edit: Found a similar answer using pack and unpack, replaced

`sprint( "%b", hex($h));`
with
`unpack( 'B*', pack('H*' ($h))`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What leading zeros? Please provide a [mcve] with example input and your code that you're referring to. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Indeed!  Plus, Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the width of the output in `sprintf` or `printf` by putting the number between the % and the format character like this.

```
printf "%16b\n",hex("0132");
```

and by preceding the number with 0, make it pad the result with 0s like this

```
printf "%016b\n",hex("0132");
```

the latter giving the result of

> 0000000100110010

But this is all covered in the documentation for those functions.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses the length of the hex repesentation to determine the length of the binary representation:

```
for my $num_hex (@nums_hex) {
   my $num = hex($num_hex);
   my $num_bin = sprintf('%0*b', length($num_hex)*4, $num);
   ...
}
```